# How to migrate Netty 3.6 to Netty 4.0 for server chunked responses?

Tags: netty

I've been looking to see how to upgrade a netty 3.x server that uses chunked responses to 4.0. In 3.6.X, I used the `DefaultHttpChunk` and `DefaultHttpChunkTrailer` classes to do this, but I can't quite figure out how to map to the new classes in 4.0. The two implementations of `HttpResponse` let me to believe that `DefaultHttpResponse` could act the the chunked portion, but I see no equivalent to `DefaultHttpChunkTrailer` so I can set the trailers.

Can somebody point me in the right direction? Also is there a rough idea as to when 4.0 will be code complete and released?

Thanks,
Senthil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its now like this:

HttpChunk -> HttpContent

LastHttpChunk -> LastHttpContent

HttpResponse / HttpRequest just hold the headers etc but no content.